# I'm having several WP issues, especially with missing images

Tags: plugins, images, cache

My site is at http://www.aviewtoathrill.net. I have deactivated all of my plugins in the hopes of getting my images to show up on the site. Since it is a travel site, images are crucial. I think the problem began when I installed w3 total cache because the site was very slow. That plugin caused me to have lots of problems with redirection. I installed disable canonical url plugin which helped temporarily until the whole site crashed. I uninstalled both of those plugins. Also, I switched hosts from fatcow to stablehost, so I'm not sure if that may have affected things. Additionally, I upgraded my wordpress from 2.9 to 3.1.

Secondly, I realize with all of my images, I need external storage. I have started an amazon s3 and cloudfront account. However, I can't figure out how to transfer the files/folders. Please feel free to ask for clarification. I'm sure it sounds like I'm rambling, I just want to find someone who can fix my problem completely for once and for all.

Oh, I just reinstalled my broken links plugin and it says that 534 image links are broken....just thought that I would add that.

Thank you!

Renee

Comment: Hi Renee, users are most certainly motivated to answer concrete questions, however, as nobody here knows your site's details I fear it's not really solveable in that format. And this is not a job offer board.

Answer (score 1):

your site domain uses the www, but your images are all with paths http://aviewtoathrill.net (no www.). they are all returning 403 forbidden status codes, so my guess is that you have some sort of hotlink protection that is preventing your site from loading its own images due to this mismatch.

EDIT - everything seems to work fine if I remove the www and browse that way. You should 301 redirect one to the other and just force one version of your url.